# Invalid Date moment.js using Iso yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I have a date in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss that I am using to create moments for x axes values in chart.js
I get invalid date when I am newing up an instance of the moment.js class

[image]

```
$.each(unique, function (index, value) {                    
                var momentDate = moment(value, "DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss");
                momentsArray.push(momentDate);
            });
```

I have read the documentation and I believe I am following the right ISO format for creating moment.js object. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please share some code, so we can see how you are formatting your data

Comment: If the format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, then why do you tell moment to expect DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss format?

Comment: I thought that moment(value, "DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss")  provides the value and specifices the format it wants the moment to be in.

Comment: Might want to [look at the docs again](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 0):

According to your date value **"2020-10-19 15:50:20"**, your format string should be **"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"**